# How to find similar webdesign to specific sites? (Zendesk / Mailchimp)

Tags: web-development, website-design

For a new project we are looking for good webdesign examples. Some of our favorite sites include Zendesk.com or Mailchimp.com.

How would you approach to find similar sites?

PS: We also appreciate concrete examples if you know any.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited for  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned in the comments that neither you nor your partner are designers. So the obvious thing to do is go about finding a designer or design studio to handle the design for you. You already have 2 examples of sites you like the designs of; if you find a designer with a portfolio that also matches your tastes and show them those two sites, they'll be able to work with you to come up with a design that suits your needs.

There are a lot of sites out there dedicated to showcasing good designs or design blogs that post good designs for inspiration. But, while it's nice when a client comes to us already with lots of examples of what they like or the look they want to shoot for, you really need to get a professional designer as early as possible if you're not one yourself.

First of all, one of the main reasons you hire a professional designer is because they have a trained aesthetic eye; they grasp design theory and understand its elements; they can identify what specifically makes a good design so good or a bad design bad, and they also know the practical requirements of this particular media.

So they're not just a button pusher you hire to operate a graphics program for you or duplicate examples you give them. They're providing you with a complete design process, which includes the research and brainstorming phase. That's why it's better to bring a designer in early and have them help you with this.

Otherwise, you may be wasting your time by collecting a bunch of useless examples that either don't apply to your project, are redundant, have completely disparate and incompatible looks, or are just outright bad designs.

On the other hand, if you go through this process with a professional designer, they'll be able to help you identify what specifically you like about Zendesk or MailChimp, determine if it applies to your project, and then, if necessary, help you find more relevant examples in a similar vein. In other words, the design examples they help you obtain will be deliberately chosen, not just because you like the way it looks. So it'll take fewer but more purposefully chosen examples to hone in on exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer. We defenitely get a designer to it very soon (within) days.
But here are some questions we have to think of:
1. We did not decide yet which style we like more (zendesk or mailchimp). Thats why we like to find some more examples to help us.
2. Like I mentioned before. We do not want to provide only 1 example. We dont want the designer to focus too much on it (and maybe copy it).

But you are probably also right. A good designer can probably help us with all these questions... :)

Comment: Have a look at http://www.designfridge.co.uk/ for some inspiration for design.

Comment: @Daniel: You could check out Behanced, Creattica, Design Fridge, etc. where designers post their own designs to showcase their work. This way, not only are you seeing lots of great designs, but when you find one that you particularly like, you can contact the designer to see about hiring them. And typically if you find a designer with a fairly large/diverse portfolio, you can be sure they'll be able to come up with something that looks good but is still completely original and not worry about their copying a particular example.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out the recent incident of curebit copying 100% highrisehq.com and getting caught. http://techcrunch.com/2012/01/28/curebit-apologizes-for-copying-37signals/ and http://www.pixelonomics.com/curebit-copied-highrises-design-html/

If you plan on using zendesk or mailchimp or any other site for that matter, only use their designs for inspiration not to copy. Come up with your own design. If you already like zendesk and mailchimp get stated on your own custom site

Comment: We do not intend to copy anyone. But me and my partner are no designers and would like to get some more examples. Exactly for the reason that we don't want to copy a site.
Thanks

Comment: Google, search Google, if zendesk is a helpdesk SaaS application, why not Google some of the keywords in their title, or body and find similar sites. MailChimp email campaign management. Google some of those keywords.

Comment: Speaking of 37signals copies. They probably have not seen this one yet: http://www.collabor8online.co.uk/ ;-)

Comment: Anagio: We tried that. Have you seen the AWeber site? (like Mailchimp) Looks like made 10 years ago ;-)

Comment: You tried Googling? What was the problem?